# creating frames with tabs in a PyQt4 app

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt, frame

so basically with the help of someone I was able to come up with code for creating a GUI which has two frames. One on the left and one on the right. But I am having trouble writing the same code for a real application.

I.e. the code here is very basic as it just contains a main function. How do I rewrite this code with reference to self like how I tried in here.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt4 Tuts")
        self.home()


    def home(self):

        mainWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
        mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(mainWindow)

        frameLeft = QtGui.QFrame(mainWindow)
        frameLeft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frameLeft.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        gridLayoutLeft = QtGui.QGridLayout(frameLeft)
        mainLayout.addWidget(frameLeft, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        frameRigth = QtGui.QFrame(mainWindow)
        frameRigth.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frameRigth.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        gridLayoutRigth = QtGui.QGridLayout(frameRigth)
        mainLayout.addWidget(frameRigth, 0, 1, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        tabs    = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        gridLayoutRigth.addWidget(tabs, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('test')
        gridLayoutLeft.addWidget(button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Create tabs
        tab1    = QtGui.QWidget()   
        tab2 = QtGui.QWidget()

        # Set layout of first tab
        vBoxlayout  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        pushButton1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Settings")
        pushButton3 = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
        vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton1)
        vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton2)
        vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton3)
        tab1.setLayout(vBoxlayout)   

        # Add tabs
        tabs.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")
        tabs.addTab(tab2, "Tab 2")

        mainWindow.show()

        self.show()

    def close_application(self):
        print("Whooaa so custom!")
        sys.exit()

def run():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI=Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

My main problem is that in here I have self.show() but also mainWindow.show() I dont know which one to use or how to eliminate one so that I need only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the ball rolling:

```
mainWindow.show() # not this, this is a "QWidget"
self.show() # use this, this is a "QMainWindow"
```

you wanna "show" the the `QMainWindow`, the class you just implemented.
Furthermore this class need content, which you correctly gathered in `mainwindow`, so use `setCentralWidget()`:

```
self.setCentralWidget(mainWindow)
self.show()
```

and finally `close_application()` is never called, you can either connect it to a button:

```
pushButton3.clicked.connect(self.close_application)
```

or overwrite the closingEvent:

```
def closeEvent ( self, QCloseEvent ) :
    print("Whooaa so custom, that is closing now!")
    #QCloseEvent.accept()
```